# Debugging RealityKit CustomMaterial shaders

Tags: xcode, debugging, shader, metal, realitykit

I've been creating metal shaders for RealityKit custom materials for my IOS app, the problem that I have right now is that I can't seem to be able to debug my shader.
Looking up online, everyone says that XCode debugger should work just fine, with breakpoints and all. But when I added breakpoint to my shader code and run the app in simulator, the breakpoints sign will turn into an outline shape and I never able to debug my shader properly.

Is there a way to do better debug my shaders?
Thanks!

ps : I'm trying on XCode 15 beta, but XCode 14 shows the same behavior in debugging.

Comment: Have you pressed the Metal capture button? It's the `M` above left of the Console.

Comment: Yup, I finally stumbled upon an article that goes in depth more than the Apple documentation but now I'm stuck in trying to debug them cause it says "Unable to create shader debug session" and I've tried to follow this :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building-your-project-with-embedded-shader-sources

Is it because I'm doing an iOS app instead of macOS?

Comment: I've encountered the "Unable to create shader debug session" error when trying to debug a huge shader all at once. Might want to try selective debugging.